# String match between two columns

Tags: python, string

Below code does not work need help. I am trying to compare two column using python. I want to check if string under column 'c1' is in column "Name". Result I want is either 1 or 0

```
for i in string_match["c1"]:
for j in string_match["Name"]:
    if i in j:
        result = "1"
    else:
        result = "0"
```

this is the alternate option which worked.
string_match['new'] = string_match.apply(lambda x: x.c1 in x.Component_Name_EDS, axis=1)

[image: table]

Comment: if alternate solution worked, what do you want then?

Comment: I have mention in the question I guess, I still need to understand why the 1st approach did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I misunderstood your question.
If you want to compare only respective row to the first column string. following should work, here `a` and `b` are columns of the dataframe

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.a in x.b, axis=1)
```

but If you want to compare each word to every other word in second column and return 1 if matches to any one of the string in second column, then

```
for word in df.a:
 print("1" if any(df.b.apply(lambda x: word in x)) else "0")
```

Although this is not the most efficient solution, you can always use hashing for string comparison.